# ReferenceError: app is not defined: node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs, node-modules

I wants to get a dashboard page but unable to get it due to issues which are not fixing can I get help here

userControler:

```
     const express = require('express');
     const router = express.Router();
     const mongoose = require('mongoose');
     const session = require('express-session');
     const passport = require('passport');
     const User = mongoose.model('User');

   app.router('/dashboard', (req, res) => { 
console.log("test");
User.find((err, docs) => { 
    if (!err) { res.render("dashboard", {
                   users: docs
               });
     } else { 
        console.log('Error in retrieving users list :' + err);
         } 
     }); 
  });
```

route in app.js

```
   app.use('dashboard', userController);
```

dashboard.ejs:

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">users</label>
                                                                                                                          <% users.forEach(function (users) { %>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
       <option><%= users.name %></option>
    </select>
    <% }) %>
  </div>
```

error:

```
   the options [userNewParser] is not supported
   D:\nodejs\node_app\controllers\userController.js:10
   app.router('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
   ^

   ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

dashboard.ejs:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">users</label>
        <% users.forEach(function (users) { %>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
          <option><%= users.name %></option>
        </select>
        <% }) %>
      </div>
```

app.js

```
   paste.ofcode.org/7zJVKxxhRan2KgskF37ixL
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Hello World" [example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

Comment: Where is `app` defined?

Comment: check the error in updated question

Comment: @RolandStarke can u plz tell me how to resolve it coz m new to it from php

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. `app` variable is not defined, so obviously you can not use it. Check example from the link in first comment to see how you should define it.

Comment: you have not defined the `app` in `userController`. Look at the documentation of `express.Router()`

Comment: @UsamaTahir if I write router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => { 
 then it says  TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Comment: @rkm I write router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => { then it says TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Comment: plz check app.js in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again

userControler:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const session = require('express-session');
  const passport = require('passport');
  const User = mongoose.model('User');

  router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => { 
    console.log("test");
    User.find((err, docs) => { 
    if (!err) { res.render("dashboard", {
                 users: docs
             });
    } else { 
      console.log('Error in retrieving users list :' + err);
       } 
    }); 
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
  var userControler = require('./userControler.js');
  // ...
  app.use('/dashboard', userControler);
```

Comment: D:\nodejs\node_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:160
  req.next = next;
           ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string 'dashboard'
    at Function.handle (D:\nodejs\node_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:160:12)
    at router (D:\nodejs\node_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_app\controllers\userController.js:9:1)

Comment: by using /dashboard or by using dashboard same result

Comment: router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => { 
    // ...
});

Comment: that one is removed and now it says: ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\node_app\views\dashboard.ejs:13
    11|   <div class="form-group">
    12|     <label for="exampleInputPassword1">users</label>
 >> 13|     <% users.forEach(function (users) { %>
    14|     <select class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
    15|       <option><%= users.name %></option>
    16|     </select>

users is not defined

Comment: can u plz see it from question

Answer (score 0):

you can call router with express in direct way.

```
`const router = express();`
```

You don't need to use as `const router = express.Router();`

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.